# REST: Seperate API endpoints for user images and all images?

Tags: rest, api

I'm designing an API for a website where users can share images and all other users can see these images. The current idea is to have a path 
`/user/name/images/xyz` to GET a user's image and then a path `images/abc` to GET any public image "`abc`." I'm worried that there is a design flaw if I'm separating image retrieval across multiple endpoints. What's the most proper way to design this?

Comment: Where does the "xyz" or "abc" come from? Is that an id that will be generated by your system or is it something that is controlled by a user?

Comment: Sorry that's meant to be an id, possibly a hashcode or something uniquely identifying of the image.

Answer (score 1):

The URL `/users/NAME/images/XYZ` infers that image XYZ is a subresource of user NAME. This also means that `/users/bob/images/XYZ` and `/users/edna/images/XYZ` are *different* images even though they share the same name (XYZ). If no such semantic relationship exists, or no two images should have the same name, then  `/images/XYZ` is preferable.

Now imagine what happens if the client requests `/users/NAME/images`. Should they get a list of images filtered by that user? What happens if the client requests `/images`?

The answers to these questions can help drive your URL structure.

Comment: I think images should not strictly be a subresource of `user/NAME`. I guess that I'm asking whether it's okay design to have a `/images/XYZ` for any image and `/user/NAME/images/` to get the collection of user images? Or does this overlapping "resource" indicate a flaw in design.